# Wie antwortet man auf "Ich wünsche dir was" und was genau bedeutet die Aussage?

Tags: phrase

Meine Nachbarin sagt mir oft beim Abschied

> "Ich wünsche dir was"

Wie kann man darauf höflich antworten und was genau bedeutet dieses "was"?

Comment: "Ich wünsche dir das gleiche!" <g>

Comment: "was" ist in diesem Fall die Kurzform von "etwas".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normalerweise wünscht man sich zum Abschied etwas Konkretes – einen schönen restlichen Abend, ein schönes Wochenende, gute Besserung, eine schöne Reise oder wahlweise auch die Pest an den Hals.
Das „was“ lässt offen, was genau jetzt gewünscht wird, und erspart es damit dem Sprecher, sich eine passende Formulierung auszudenken. Damit ist es natürlich nicht ganz so persönlich, aber einfacher und universell einsetzbar.

Außerdem lässt es offen, ob jetzt etwas Positives oder etwas Negatives gemeint ist, aber solange Du keinen Anlass hast zu glauben, dass Deine Nachbarin sehr durchtrieben ist oder Dich hasst, kannst Du davon ausgehen, dass es ein nett gemeinter Abschiedsgruß ist.

Eine passende Antwort kann im Prinzip jede Art von Abschiedsgruß sein:

> Einen schönen Tag/Abend noch!
>
> Auf Wiedersehen!

oder mit direktem Bezug auf ihren Abschiedsgruß:

> Danke, (ich) Ihnen/Dir auch!

Comment: Man könnte auch etwas schnippisch zurückgeben _'Hoffentlich was Gutes!'_ @Rudy Velthuis hatte das kommentiert mit _"Oder 'Ich wünsche dir (genau) das gleiche'. Dann ist es egal, ob es die Pest oder ein schönes Wochenende war._ Ich weiß nicht, wie man einen Post in einen Kommentar verschieben kann - die Kommentare sind dann weg, oder?

Comment: @Ralf Joerres: Ja, "Hoffentlich was Gutes" ist schnippisch, und würde bei mir als "Wünschenden" kein gutes Gefühl zurücklassen, es sei denn, ein solcher Umgang wäre gang und gäbe zwischen mir und meinem Gegenüber.

Comment: Vielen Dank für die Antwort! Ich habe bisher auch rein intuitiv "Dir auch!" geantwortet, war mir aber nicht sicher, ob man es wirklich so sagen kann, wenn einem nichts Bestimmtes gewünscht wird.

Answer (score 2):

Anders als »Schleich dich!« oder »Mach dich vom Acker!« enthält das, was du hörst, den Hinweis auf ein gutes nachbarschaftliches Verhältnis.

Gratulation.

»Ich wünsch[e] dir was!« heißt so viel wie »Ich wünsche dir etwas Gutes!« oder umständlicher und überzogen formuliert: »Es ist mein ausdrücklicher Wunsch, mein lieber Igor, dass dir etwas Gutes widerfährt!«

Als höfliche Antwort kannst du dich beispielsweise lächelnd bedanken, gefolgt von einem Abschiedsgruß, z. B. mit

> Danke! Tschau!

Du kannst aber auch launig sagen:

> Und ich dir noch mehr!

---

Ähnliches wie deine Nachbarin sagte einmal ein Clochard zu meinem Kumpel und mir:

> Ich wünsch euch verdammt viel!

Ein Scherzbold.

Comment: Auch wenn ich deine Antwort unterhaltsamer fand (die sprachliche Qualität muss man auch mal loben), beleuchtet Lykanions Antwort, meiner Meinung nach, die Thematik ein wenig besser.

Comment: @Devon Die Antwort beleuchtet die "subtile" Bedeutung schon ziemlich gut finde ich, und trifft den Punkt ziemlich genau. Die Unsicherheit was "was" in dieser Allgemein eher positiv verwendeten/konnotierten Phrase bedeutet ist hier besser dargestellt. Mein Upvote daher.

Comment: Danke auch für diese Antwort! Ist es übrigens unhöflich, wenn man seinem Gegenüber nicht auch etwas wünscht, gerade wenn ich einfach nur "Danke! Tschau!" sagen würde?

Comment: @IgorO.: Wer sich bedankt und dann auch noch freundlich dazu lächelt, dürfte kaum als unhöflich angesehen werden. _»Danke, ebenso!«_ ist eine häufige Antwort auf _»Einen schönen Tag noch!«_; als Antwort auf _»Ich wünsch dir was!«_ käme mir das etwas komisch vor.

Comment: @IgorO.: Noch ein Tipp: Komme deiner Nachbarin beim nächsten Mal einfach zuvor. Sage ihr _»Ich wünsch dir was!«_ und höre dir an, was sie erwidert. Das kannst du dann übernehmen.

Comment: @Pollitzer.: Ich traue mich oft nicht Phrasen oder Wörter zu verwenden, deren Bedeutung ich nicht genau weiß, ist aber zugegeben eine schlaue Taktik :) Vielen Dank auch für die Tipps!